# Reload same view controller again and again

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

Reload same view controller again and again with animation like navigation controller

I have a list of users and when clicking one of the users it shows its details in an another UItableviewcontroller

What I want is to swipe(or interactive pop gesture) the details page view and show the details for next or previous user (depending on the swipe gesture), it should reload the new view controller with animation like navigation controller interactive pop gesture.

Please let me know if more explanation is needed

Please look at [Android Example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) 'Zoom-out page transformer'

Comment: then what do you mean by again and again ? When you present a detail view from the table view, you will loose the reference to the tableview data. You cant simply swipe on detail view to present the next row data. IF you want to do anything, you need to do it on the tableview!!!!

Comment: I can reload the data in table view and show but It would be nice if there is a animation like in Settings. In settings go to any detail page and try swiping back I am trying to get some thing like that

Comment: Just update the views in the existing controller. On your first segue pass the current index of the row that was selected and the current tables data source to the detail controller. Then on swipe update the visual elements using some kind of UIView animation.

Comment: @thefredelement  I am already doing that, just want that animation I mentioned in the above comment and it should be like all page is changing rather than row wise

Comment: Look at the view animation docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html - There are plenty of examples on SO too. I do something like this where things animate dif. depending on swipe direction.

Comment: @thefredelement please look at http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html
Zoom-out page transformer 
I want some thing like that

Comment: cool, you can absolutely do that with animations and scaling. Play around with it and put some code attempts in your question.

Comment: @thefredelement but will it be possible to show 2 tableview (look at android example) at same time one for the current one and one for the next or prev one?

Comment: yes, you can do it with animations in a custom segue or animations with UIViews. I suggest you start coding and ask a more specific question if you have a problem.

Comment: tried a lot and but can't find a solution, All I was able to bring up is using UITableViewRowAnimation and handling UISwipeGestureRecognizer but its not cool as the example I have shown you :(